# Plug in a USB mouse makes computer shuts down after a while

Tags: usb, mouse, shutdown, overheating, peripherals

When I plug my USB mouse on my laptop starts to overheating and shuts down after a while. What can I do to solve this problem?

Linux Xubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bits

Comment: Are you 100% sure this never, EVER happens without plugging in your USB mouse? Is there some program (like a game) that you only use with your USB mouse?

Comment: Yes, today I made a zero installation of Xubuntu 16.04 amd64 and the problem was kept...